# Strange issue in header location redirect

Tags: redirect, apache2

I have three websites hosted (example1.com, example2.com, example3.com) on a server. There is a page (test.php) on example1.com with just code below inside it:

```
<?php
  header('Location:http://example2.com/a.php');
?>
```

When I browse test.php it goes to http://example1.com/a.php . it doesn't understand it is another domain url, it tried to find the page on itself.

but when I put http://google.com instead of example2.com/a.php it works correct. I really get confused.

What is the problem ? Should I set some configuration on the server?

( I am administrator of the hosting server ).
Ps. The server is behind a pound server.

Edited:

Here's the Firebug Net output for example1.com/test.php

```
Response Headers: 

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Tue, 09 Oct 2012 09:03:34 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
Location: http://example1.com/a.php
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 21
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

Request Headers:

Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
Cookie  mycookie  
Host    example1.com
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1
```

Comment: Can you post what you have in a.php on example2.com ?

Comment: there is a simple echo 'hi'; command inside it.

Comment: If you put http://example2.com/a.php in the browser, does it work correctly?

Comment: really it is tricky! .... can you please upload screenshots of the various pages / screens, that might help a bit

Comment: Post your Apache response headers on redirect when error occures.

Comment: @webbandit: I've put it in the question.please have a look at it.

Comment: make sure to add `exit;` after `header('Location:http://example2.com/a.php');`

Comment: @webbandit: I put it now ,but no differences.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is solved. it was because of pound server configuration. 'RewriteLocation' entry in pound server configuration must be set to 2 to this server doesn't change the redirect location.

anyway, thank you for answering.